# merging .nc files of copernicus

Tags: python, python-xarray, code-climate, cds.copernicus

I want to merge gridded netcdf files, although i have done it using xarray, i found nan values in some. Because i am not sure by which dimensions should i merge. Here, I am dealing with nondimensional coordinates, is there any way to convert gridded dimensions to lat,lon coordinates ,

I have merged the data,now i have no idea of how to draw 2d plot with x,y, as this contains gridded data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6kj0.jpg)